# How I can do something like "localhost/winter/2022" not "localhost/?season=winter&year=2022"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I used the GET method for season and year, but i want to make URL look better, how I can do that?

Something like: `example.com/winter/2022`

Comment: That is called "request rewriting". It is applied on protocol level, so typically inside the apache http server. You will find many tutorials explaining how that works.

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application) instead of adding a bunch of different rules in your htaccess. It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. And since you only need one single rule (that redirects all requests to non-existing files to index.php), it's easier to move it between web servers (not all use htaccess files).